# Lattice model realization of $SU(2)$ WZW model at level $k$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, lattice-model, wess-zumino-witten

Is there any lattice model realization of the following model:

> $c=1$ boson at the self-dual radius, or the $SU(2)$ WZW model at $k=1$.

This is a question inspired by: [Orbifolds of the $c =1$ Bosonic theory on a circle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6502/)

Comment: Please check spin-1/2 Heisenberg antiferromagnetic chain at zero temperature whose low-energy effective field theory is exactly SU(2) level 1 WZW model. For general SU(N) level k WZW models, there also exist their spin model partners.